# How does logic work in combination with assigning values to variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just did an exercise in my Python course and stumbled across a solution that doesn't really make sense to me.

```
def range_in_list(lst, start=0, end=None):
    end = end or lst[-1]
    return sum(lst[start : end + 1])
```

How does "or" work when assigning basically two values to a variable, does the variable have both values assigned to it?
Unfortunately, I can't find any information on this in my course nor anywhere else.

Comment: 'or' doesn't assign 2 values. In your case if end is None it (end) will receive the value of lst[-1] last item in the list. If end is not None - it will be stay the same (assume end is 5 it will remain 5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have learnt how to use the `or` and `and` operators when working with [boolean values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-boolean-values), but there is one detail you *might* be missing, and that is: how they actually work. The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) say (Emphasis mine):

> **Note that neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return
> to `False` and `True`, but rather return the last evaluated argument**. This
> is sometimes useful, e.g., if s is a string that should be replaced by
> a default value if it is empty, the expression s or 'foo' yields the
> desired value....)

As you can see, the `or` and `and` operators are not restricted to returning `True` or `False`, and I will add they are not restricted to working explicitly with boolean expressions, instead they act like expression evaluators, and return the last expression which is [`Truthy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth).

### Two lessons about the `or` operator

#### `Or` evaluates expressions

`or` will either return the value of the expression on the right side if it is [truthy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth), otherwise the expression on the left side is *evaluated*, and that becomes the result of the entire statement.

#### `Or` is lazy

Implicit in the first lesson, is the notion of lazy evaluation. It is important to understand that evaluation of the expression is not done immediately, this is another way of saying the evaluation is lazy. Consider the following:

```
v = True or <some expensive database fetch which might take long time>
```

In the above, `<some expensive database fetch which might take long time>` will never be evaluated because the left expression was truthy (actually true in this case), therefore the value of `v` will be `True`.

This concept is further solidified if you understand why the following will not raise a [`ZeroDivisionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ZeroDivisionError) exception:

```
n = 45 or (1/0)
```

Comment: Now I fully get what's happening  I suspected the direction but just wasn't able to piece together the right answer.
I think I have gotten to that point now where I definitely need to read the Python doc more 
Thanks for your fast and awesome answer, really appreciate it ❤️

Comment: @fabestah Yes the docs are very helpful and can be beneficial if you are self-studying. Glad it cleared your confusions, that's always a joy to hear.

Answer (score 0):

In python, `or` is a Boolean operator that evaluates as follows:

```py
True or True
> True
True or False
> True
False or True
> True
False or False
> False
```

`None` is neither `True` nor `False` (see [article](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_none.asp#:%7E:text=The%20None%20keyword%20is%20used,only%20None%20can%20be%20None.)), but it evaluates to `False` in an `or` operation.

On a separate note, it is not clear what this code is intended to do.  Moreover, what the code actually does, does not seem useful.  This code does not calculate the range of a list of numbers, if that is the intent.

Second, the purpose of `None` is not clear either.  My guess is that it is supposed to be a fail safe for when the list is empty, but it isn't working that way.

Comment: This is just an exercise and the task of the exercise doesn't actually have something to do with the question itself, I just included it to add a bit more context to the exercise. Thanks for your answer ❤️